# how to sort django templates folder

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i made  my first blog templates in order `blog/templates/sth.html` becuz it didnt find in this order `blog/templates/blog/sth.html` but now i made a new app and made it in order `users/templates/registiration/login.html` and got this error
Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\NDarksoul\.virtualenvs\blog-PCvr0qFP\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\blog\base.html (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\NDarksoul\.virtualenvs\blog-PCvr0qFP\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\blog\base.html (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\projects\rightnow\blog\blog\templates\blog\base.html (Source does not exist)

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\projects\rightnow\blog\users\templates\blog\base.html (Source does not exist)
```

can u hlp me pls how to fix this mess

Comment: It shows you exactly where it is looking for the template.

Comment: please provide your project structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the main **templates** folder, all folders for each app
then add in these folder their templates depend on the app
and the main template in **templates** folder.

[image]

Comment: so u create templates folder in base root then create apps folder inside templates?

Comment: nope, I created the  apps out of the templates folder (you can see search app out of templates)
But  I have added folders with my apps name (like search folder) in the templates to sort my templates files depend on the apps

Comment: ye i meant that srry, so i should add path to setting or it set it up itself?

Comment: i made it this way but it looked at this path now : 
   django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\projects\rightnow\blog\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)

Comment: no no , no thiis way, you didn't get me :)

Comment: srry i added an image of my project can u pls write templates path?[imgur](https://imgur.com/a/cwqEmVw)

Comment: i used @k.d dunno if u received my comment

Comment: check my setting : https://imgur.com/a/y9EHRvF

Comment: srry i take ur time but whats `normpath` and `dirname` u meant to use my own dirname? i used this  setting [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/dGkUhYi) srry really taking ur time